# How do I refresh every WebBrowser in a Control/Tab page?

Tags: vb.net

Yeah I'm kinda just starting out and I was wondering how you could refresh every WebBrowser that is in a control such as a TabPage (which is my situation) or a form.

I've looked it up, but can't seem to find anything. I've tried experimenting and figuring it out but this time I can't find a solution.

It might be simple and ehh but I'm a beginner so don't.

```
For every webbrowser in TabPage 3, refresh them all.. how would I do this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls 'or tabpage
If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(WebBrowser)) Then
    Dim wbr As WebBrowser = CType(ctrl, WebBrowser)
    wbr.Refresh()
End If
```

Comment: Or `Me.Controls.OfType`, then you will only get those types, then you can cast the object and call the method on the object. Also you dont need a variable to call a method on that object, `CType(ctrl, WebBrowser).Refresh()`, thats all you need. Why allocate memory if you dont need to? Also you dont need the other variable `ctrl`, `For Each ctrl As Control In ...` will suffice.

Comment: No problem! :)­